# Makefile: No rule to make target. But from what I see It shoudl be covered

Tags: c++, makefile

Hello Newcomer to makefiles here.

I am having problems understanding why my makefile wont work.
I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../obj/StageObject.o', needed by 'test_distances'.  Stop.
```

My $(OBJ_FILES) contains the following string:

```
../obj/StageObject.o ../obj/Coordinate.o ../obj/Robot.o
```

Which is fine.

What I dont understand, is that from what i see, I do have a rule that covers "../obj/StageObject.o". Namely the rule "../obj/%.o". I even tried to substitute it with "%.o", but the same response occours.

What is it that I don't see?

```
OBJ_DIR = ../obj
SRC_DIR = ../src

SRC_FILES := $(wildcard ../src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

test_distances: test_distances.o $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o test_distances $^

../obj/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.hpp
    g++ -c -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ $(SRC_DIR)/$<

test_%.o : test_%.hpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Shouldn't object files depend on the source files they are generated from?

Comment: It is every strange to pass header files to g++. Don't you mean to compile the cpp file? Also note that $@ and $< *already* contain full paths, so no need to add OBJ_DIR and SRC_DIR again.

Comment: It's not enough to have a rule that mentions a target. The rule actually has to work, and makes sense. The above makefile says that any `.o` depends on a `.hpp` with the same name (which in itself doesn't make much sense), and you probably do not have a `.hpp` file with the same name, right?

Comment: To clarify @SamVarshavchik's comment: Make has several rules built in to generate .o files (eg from .c, from .S, from .cc), but only the ones where the source file exists is actually considered as a candidate. So, is it possible that ../src/StageObject.hpp does not exist? And shouldn't you be compiling ../src/StageObject.cpp ?

Comment: Try to run `make -d` and analyze output - what files have been considered and you will find out why the rule is rejected (most probably your dependency `../src/StageObject.hpp` does not exist).

Comment: @Botje Yes Indeed, that is certainly a mistake. It shoult have been .cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, changing from hpp to cpp solved my problem. Indeed i am using .h and not .hpp as file extension names. Running make with -d as also stated in the comments is quite usefull.